# How to print a float variable along with a string in the same line

Tags: python, string, output

Ok, so I want to print a float variable along with a sentence (not just the variable). The name of the variable is `discount`. I have previously declared the variable. I can get it to print the variable alone. I did `print(float(discount))` and that displays the float, but I want to print `"The discount is" (discount)`. I tried:

```
print("The discount is" float(discount))
```

and that did not work.

Comment: Python 3.x: `print('The discount is', discount)`, Python 2.x: `print 'The discount is', discount`

Comment: You can't declare a variable in Python. You can only initialize it by assigning to it. Also, why do you need to call `float` on `discount`? It should print just fine without that, even if the type isn't `float`.

Comment: @jpmc26 I am very proficient in C++ and new to Python so messing with small stuff like this confuses me since it is different. That's why I am having this problem. And the type will never be int because there are 4 different percentages of discount from 99 dollars. 10, 20, 30, and 40 percent. And sorry I didn't mean declare I meant assign. The variable should be 99*.1 (discount = 99*.1).

Comment: @Jesse I'm happy to hear you're learning about Python. =) I think you'll find that what Python does differently will make you rethink a lot of paradigms and ideas. (It certainly did for me coming from a Java/.NET background.) Let me rephrase. The `float` function takes an input and converts it to a float. Why do you need to convert to float? If `discount` happens to be a string or an integer or any other type, does that really make a difference, or would you be just fine printing it out anyway? Or can you be sure enough that's it's already a float that you don't need to convert?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `format` function to print it.

```
print('The discount is {}'.format(float(discount)))
```

Example

```
discount = 15
print('The discount is {}'.format(float(discount)))

The discount is 15.0
```

Since your example appears to be monetary you can use the following to print two decimal places

```
print("${:.2f}".format(float(discount)))

The discount is $15.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a comma between the string literal and `float(discount)`:

```
>>> discount = 25
>>> print("The discount is", float(discount))
The discount is 25.0
>>>
```

If you are using Python 2.x, you will need to write it like so:

```
>>> discount = 25
>>> print "The discount is", float(discount)
The discount is 25.0
>>>
```